# Can someone explain the behavior of my right-shift in C?

Tags: c, shift

I don't understand the outcome of the following code:

```
unsigned char p = 170;
p = (~p) >> 4 & 255;
```

The Result is: 245 and I don't understand why.

First the     (~p) will applied what makes 10101010 to 01010101

This is a positive number so >> 4 would lead to 00000101 in my understanding.

But it seems to be 11110101 and I don't understand why. In my understanding shifting a positive number to the right will insert 0 and not 1.

Comment: @WaqasShabbir it is unsigned ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When used in an expression, an integer narrower than `int` is generally converted to an `int`. So, using 16-bit `int` for illustration, in `(~p) >> 4 & 255`:

- `p` is 10101010<sub>2</sub>.
- This is converted to an `int`, producing 0000000010101010<sub>2</sub>.
- `~p` produces 1111111101010101<sub>2</sub>.
- `(~p) >> 4` may produce 1111111111110101<sub>2</sub>. (Right-shift of negative values is implementation-defined.)
- `(~p) >> 4 & 255` produces 11110101<sub>2</sub>.
- 11110101<sub>2</sub> is 245.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sence, i totally forget about the convertion!